# Using a variable defined in another function

Tags: c, linux, function, scoping

I'm trying to control a joystick, written some code using the API to do so.
I've read the number of axes on the joystick in function a using `ioctl(fd, JSIOCGAXES, &axes);` and want to then print the axis that was moved in the event-handling function (function b):

```
char whichaxis[axes] = {'X','Y','Y','X'};
printf("%c%c |%8hd\n",whichjs,whichaxis[jse.number],jse.value);
```

This code should print something like `LX| -32768`, saying that the left joystick has moved in the x direction.

However, this returns an error, as I am calling `axes` in function `b` but it is not defined in function `b`.
So my question is, how can I use `axes` despite it not being defined in function `b`?

Here is the code

```
// Returns info about the joystick device
void print_device_info(int fd) {
    int axes=0, buttons=0;
    char name[128];
    ioctl(fd, JSIOCGAXES, &axes);
    ioctl(fd, JSIOCGBUTTONS, &buttons);
    ioctl(fd, JSIOCGNAME(sizeof(name)), &name);
    printf("%s\n  %d Axes %d Buttons\n", name, axes, buttons);
}

// Event handler
void process_event(struct js_event jse) {
     // Define which axis is which
     //        Axis number {0,1,2,3} */
     char whichaxis[axes] = {'X','Y','Y','X'};
     //Define which joystick is moved
     char whichjs = '*';
     switch(jse.number) {
         case 0: case 1:
             whichjs = 'L';
             break;
         case 2: case 3:
             whichjs = 'R';
             break;
         default:
             whichjs = '*';
             break;
     }
     // Print which joystick, axis and value of the joystick position
     printf("%c%c |%8hd\n",whichjs,whichaxis[jse.number],jse.value);
}
```

Comment: Please post some details (function where it is defined and function b).

Comment: In `printf("%c%c |%8hd\n",whichjs,whichaxis,jse.value);` `whichaxis` should be `whichaxis[jse.number]`. `whichaxis` is a pointer.

Comment: good point- changed in code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`axes` is a local variable that is declared inside a function. A local variable can only be used in the function where it is declared. A global variable is a variable that is declared outside all functions. So make `axes` a global variable which can be used in all functions.

```
int axes; // Global declaration makes axes which as scope in all below functions

void print_device_info(int fd) {
    ...
    ioctl(fd, JSIOCGAXES, &axes);
    ...

void process_event(struct js_event jse) {
    char whichaxis[axes] = {'X','Y','Y','X'};
    ...
```

Comment: how? logically it makes sense to define it in the device info function

Comment: @theoB610 `int axes` in function `print_device_info()` has local scope, making the variable is valid and can use within that function. If this is declared as global it is accessible in multiple scopes.

Answer (score 2):

Either, you can use a global variable `axes` or pass axes as a parameter in both or one of the function.

If it is not possible to pass as a parameter (because it is a callback), then you can make function such as `GetAxes()` to give current axes or use a global variable.

Comment: I'd say use a global or a non-const pointer to axes, so you can modify it.

Comment: Also, how do I pass axes as a parameter?

Comment: @theoB610: In your case, it seems a problem to pass as parameter to handler function. You can use a global variable.